# Display the first tab of a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9, netbeans6.8, jtabbedpane

I have a Jtabbedpane which contains 4 tabs (each one a Jpanel).

When I run the application from netbeans 6.8 the selected tab will be the same one as it was selected before closing the application.

Is there a way to select the first tab (index 0) each time I run my application?
Here is the Code:

```
mainTabbedPanel = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
mainTabbedPanel.setName("mainTabbedPanel");
mainTabbedPanel.addTab(resourceMap.getString("panel1"), panel1);
mainTabbedPanel.addTab(resourceMap.getString("panel2"), panel2);
mainTabbedPanel.addTab(resourceMap.getString("panel3"), panel3);
mainTabbedPanel.addTab(resourceMap.getString("panel4"), panel4);
```

Those are in the method private void initComponents() of netbeans
and on startup (constructor of my application) initComponents will be called.
I try to put mainTabbedPanel.setSelectedIndex(0) after calling initComponents() but didn't work.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29

Comment: @JB_Nizet There however is something really weird concerning the fact that this application memorizes JTabbedPane state. i guess it has something to do with the way it was built (ie using Matisse).

Comment: @Riduidel yes you are right. but i didn't find how to always display the first tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed. But I wouldn't be surprised if the (now dead) swing application framework stored this kind of preference (like the frame size and position) when the application ends.

Comment: @JB Nizet do you have any suggestions to fix this isse. the setselectedindex and setselectedcomponent does not work ???

Comment: @Joe123 updaate your question with explanations regarding the failures of `setSelectedIndex(0)` (like exception stack trace, source code, ...) and maybe we will try to save this question.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually there is no error generated from the setselectedIndex(0). I just design my app using netbeans 6.8 and when loading the application i setselectedindex(0) but the tab will be always as the one previously checked. Is there a way to not allow the application to memorizes JtabbedPane state?

Comment: update your question with the source code used to create, and display the tabbed pane.

Comment: @camickr: In future, rather than adding the same comment five times, just vote to reopen.  Alternatively, you can flag for a moderator to review the closure, or make a plea on [meta], optionally editing to clarify.

Comment: @will, Voting to reopen is a waste of time. People don't read a posting once it is closed. In fact there was no need to reopen because the poster got an answer. Why did you delete the comments? My comment was specifically directed at the 5 individuals who closed the posting without reason. The poster had a specific question. The poster responded to any comments made to try to help improve the question. The way people treat new posters on this forum is terrible. Give people a little power and they abuse it!

Comment: @camickr: First, voting to reopen is *not* a waste of time.  I deleted the comments because they were noise, and because I agreed with you and reopened, thus making them obsolete.  I'd suggest you visit [meta] and search for the many questions discussing the treatment of new users.  If you *see* anyone abusing a new user, by all means flag for moderator attention.  But do realize we *require all users* to ask *good questions*.  New or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Reopening a question after an answer have been accepted is pointless. The problem was closing the question in the first place. It was a reasonable question. The environment (Netbeans) was stated. A specific question was asked. Attempted solution using the setSelectedIndex() was stated. The point of addressing the 5 indiduals who closed the question was to point out that they abused their power of closing a question so that it hopefully doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the first tab will be selected. If something other than this is happening then there must be code somewhere that is using the setSelectedIndex(...) to reset the tab. You need to search the generated code to find out where this is and remove the code.

If you don't know how to remove the code then you can try to reset the index after the default code is executing. This is done by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater after the GUI is visible. Your code would be something like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joe123 obviously it works, like documentation could have explained you far faster. However I don't consider that to be good for you, as this question clearly exists in StackOverflow memory.

Comment: @Riduidel, again you still don't understand the problem. By default the first tab is displayed. There is no need to manually set the index to 0. So "read the API" is not the simple answer as you are implying. My answer gave the potential reason for the problem and the solution. Again, if somewhere in the code the selected tab is manually set then the location in the code where you reset the selected tab to 0, is important, hence the potential need for the invokeLater(). So it is NOT obvious what the solution is. A better suggestion would be to post a SSCCE.